# python3: How to append a list to an empty list in an external python file?

Tags: python-3.x

There is a list-

```
#main_file.py
f = ['foo','bar']
```

that I want to append to an empty list in an external python file.
The external file already has an empty list **g**

```
#external_file.py
g = []
```

So far I have tried this in the main file-

```
#main_file.py
h = open("external_file.py", "a")
g.append(f)
h.close()
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
import re

with open("external_file.py", "r+") as h:
    stmt = h.read()
    exec(stmt)
    val_name = stmt[:stmt.find("=")].strip()
    eval(val_name).extend(f)
    h.seek(0)
    h.write(re.sub("\[.*\]", str(eval(val_name)), stmt))
```

Because you are reading for a file then the statement `"g = []"` is text so you need to `exec()` it the it will be converted to `g = []`. 
After there is a need to extend the f list in to the g and to remove the original `"g = []"` with the new extended list and write it back to the file.

Comment: There's an error which says ```File "passwordManagerList.py", line 100, in passEnter
    g.extend(passList)```
```name 'g' is not defined```

Comment: You can try now I changed the file mode to be r+ and `h.write(re.sub("\[.*\]", g, stmt))` to `h.write(re.sub("\[.*\]", str(g), stmt))`

Comment: g is the name from the list the defined in the file if it's a different name put the name instead of g

Comment: I edited the code the run dynamically on a list name as long as the file that the original list contains `list_name = list_content`

Comment: it worked! but it throws syntax error when i put it on loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214114/discussion-between-ayush-and-leo-arad).

Answer (score 1):

You can try by importing the first `external_file.py` and then append the list `f` from the `main_file.py`

```
#main_file.py

import external_file as externalFile
f = ['foo','bar']
externalFile.g.append(f)
#print(externalFile.g)
```

Comment: I tried this but it isn't editing the code in the external_file